# ionic 4 - making a ion-select with segmets or introducing labels between options

Tags: forms, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to implement a ion-select item with multiple selection possible. In the dropdown alert I want to add some segments separated by a label. Here is an example of what I want to achieve (link with the photo bellow). Can someone helpe out? I'm using ionic 4 and the ion-select is dinamic.

```
<ion-item>
     <ion-label position="floating">Operations *</ion-label>
     <ion-select multiple="true" formControlName="operations">
       <ng-container *ngFor="let task of tasks">
         <ion-select-option *ngIf="task.type === 'ANALYSIS'" [value]="task">{{task.op}}
         </ion-select-option>
       </ng-container>
     </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

[photo of an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo5A1.png)

Comment: given complexity of such UI - did you consider using a modal with a component that uses ion-list, ion-list-divider etc approach vs trying to incorporate the logic into the ion-options? ion-options was meant to be lightweight options chooser and for more complex stuff its best to consider custom component in a modal.

Comment: using a model will undermine the form UI. Isn't it possible to add just some labels to the ion-selection, or some work around?

Comment: ion-options is the same modal, modals come as overlay on top of your main content so unsure how would that undermine the UI. Modifying ion-options is not trivial due to shadow dom

Comment: if using ion-select with multiple options, it will use an alert window and not a modal. Am I wrong?